# How can I access variables in a function from the global scope?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I can’t access variables in a function from the global scope. Normally I can access variables in the other function.

How can I use the `str` variable in the following code in the global scope?

```
 <html>
 <script>
 function myf(){
 str = "Change";
 document.write(str); 
 }
 document.write(str); // can not access str
 </script>
 <input type="button" value="OPEN" onclick="myf();">
 </html>
```

Comment: You need to execute a function at least, before using "str" variable else where.

Comment: “Normally I can access variables in the other function.” — I’m not quite sure what you mean in this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `str` globally to explicitly set it's scope.

```
var str;
function myf(){
  str = "Change";
  document.write(str); 
}
myf();
document.write(str); // can access str
```

Keep in mind that without the call to `myf()` the value of `str` remains `undefined`.

In general, you don't want to modify global variables inside a function because of dependency issues. Consider something like:

```
function myf() {
  return "Change";
}
document.write(myf());
```

Or if you need state:

```
function myf() {
  var state = "Change";
  return {
    get_state: function () {
      return state;
    },
    set_state: function () {
      //
    }
  }
}

var f = myf();
document.write(f.get_state());
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing … except that you have to run the code in the right order.

Currently you are:

1. **Defining** (but not running) a function that sets `str` and writes it to the document (deleting the existing document in the process)
2. Trying to use that variable
3. Clicking on a button which runs that function and gives the variable a value

You have to swap the order of the last two tasks … and stop using `document.write` inside the function.

It is also good practise (and required in JavaScript strict mode) to declare your variables before you use them. You should put `var str` at the top of your script.